# custom view controller transition with Custom UIModalPresentationStyle

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller

I am playing around with custom view controller transitions. This is the tutorial I am following: http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/custom-uiviewcontroller-transitions/

It slides a presented viewController from the right of the screen and than slides it back.

I'm having problem with implementing this code. This is what I got so far.

```
// this button should present viewController
    func buttonStartsPresentingPressed(){
                let reminderVC = UIViewController()
                reminderVC.transitioningDelegate = self
                reminderVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Custom
                self.presentViewController(reminderVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }

//In the same viewController
func animationControllerForPresentedController(presented: UIViewController, presentingController presenting: UIViewController, sourceController source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        let animator = TLTransitionAnimator()
        animator.presenting = true // ?????????????
        return animator
    }

    func animationControllerForDismissedController(dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        let animator = TLTransitionAnimator()
        return animator
    }

//Implementation of TLTransitionAnimator class
class TLTransitionAnimator: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {

    var presenting = true
    func transitionDuration(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> NSTimeInterval {
        return 0.5
    }
    func animateTransition(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
        let fromViewController = transitionContext.viewControllerForKey(UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey)
        let toViewController = transitionContext.viewControllerForKey(UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey)

        var endFrame = CGRectMake(80, 280, 160, 100)

        if self.presenting == true{
            fromViewController?.view.userInteractionEnabled = false
            transitionContext.containerView()?.addSubview(fromViewController!.view)
            transitionContext.containerView()?.addSubview(toViewController!.view)

            var startFrame = endFrame
            startFrame.origin.x += 320
            toViewController!.view.frame = startFrame

            UIView.animateWithDuration(self.transitionDuration(transitionContext), animations: {
                fromViewController!.view.tintAdjustmentMode = UIViewTintAdjustmentMode.Dimmed
                toViewController!.view.frame = endFrame
                }, completion: {_ in
            transitionContext.completeTransition(true)
            })

        }else{
            toViewController?.view.userInteractionEnabled = true
            transitionContext.containerView()?.addSubview(toViewController!.view)
            transitionContext.containerView()?.addSubview(fromViewController!.view)
            endFrame.origin.x += 320

            UIView.animateWithDuration(self.transitionDuration(transitionContext), animations: {
                toViewController!.view.tintAdjustmentMode = UIViewTintAdjustmentMode.Automatic
                fromViewController!.view.frame = endFrame
                }, completion: {_ in
                    transitionContext.completeTransition(true)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

When this is executed nothing happens. I basically rewrote the code to Swift but I am not sure what `animator.presenting` should be? Also I have doubts about correctness of subclassing `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning`